# New-ing string types

Tags: c#

From [Pro C#](http://www.apress.com/9781590598849/)

Referring to "New-ing" Intrinsic data types...

> All intrinsic data types support what is known as a default constructor.  It allows you to create a variable using the new keyword.
>
> [...] Object references (including strings) are set to null.

In C#, strings do not have a public default constructor.  My guess is that due to string's immutability, they have a private default constructor.  But, the context here is talking about Object references and string's as a whole while using `new`.

Because one cannot do

`String myString = new String();`

So,

`String a;`

referencing string doesn't result in a "default value".  Instead, it's a compiler error to access a.

Though

```
public class StringContainer
{
    public static string myString { get; set; }
}
```

Results in a legally accessible string (defaulted to null).  This doesn't use `new`.  It performs some kind of magical construction.

What is occurring in the `StringContainer` scenerio?  Because there appears to be no new-able default constructor in string, is this an error in the C# book?

Comment: *Results in a legally accessible string (defaulted to null).*  This is a local variable versus property behavior, not a string one.

Comment: You can do string mystring = new String() btw what if you wanted to have a string with 20 * signs.. you could so string mystring =new string s = new string( '*', 20 );: for example..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> All intrinsic data types support what is known as a default constructor. It allows you to create a variable using the new keyword.

There are an impressive number of subtle errors in that statement.

First off, there is no such thing as an "intrinsic" data type; perhaps this term is defined somewhere else in the book?

Second, it would be more accurate to say that all *struct* types have a public parameterless constructor called the "default" constructor. Some *class* types also have a public parameterless ctor; if you do not provide any ctor then the C# compiler will automatically generate a public parameterless ctor for you. If you do provide a ctor then the C# compiler will not do this for you.

Third, **constructors do not create variables**. The author is conflating a bunch of related but different things: the "new" operator, the memory manager, the constructor and the variable, and the created object. Variables are *storage locations* and are managed by the CLR; they are not *created* by the "new" operator.

The correct statement is that the "new" operator on a struct causes a variable to be created by the CLR *on the temporary storage pool*; that variable is then initialized by the memory manager, and then passed to the constructor for more initialization. The value thus created is then *copied* somewhere else. The "new" operator on a class causes the CLR to create an object *on the long-term storage pool*, and then pass a *reference* to that object to the CLR. No "variable" need be involved.

Confusing variables with objects is a very common error; it is valuable to understand the difference.

> In C#, strings do not have a public default constructor.

Correct.

> My guess is that due to string's immutability, they have a private default constructor.

Good guess, but wrong. There is no private parameterless constructor on string.

> [an auto-property or field of type string] results in a legally accessible string (defaulted to null). This doesn't use new. It performs some kind of magical construction.

It does no such thing. A null reference is not a constructed object at all. It's the absence of a constructed object!

You're basically saying that my empty garage contains a "magically constructed" non-existing car. That is an exceedingly weird way to look at an empty garage; an empty garage contains no car at all, not a magically constructed non-existing car.

> What is occurring in the StringContainer scenerio?

The containing type contains a compiler-generated field -- a variable -- of type string. Let's suppose the containing type is a struct or class. When the storage for the struct or class is initialized by the memory manager, the memory manager writes a null reference into the storage location associated with the variable.

Finally: I suspect your confusion is because you've gotten the "default constructor" and the "default value of a type" confused. For a struct, they are the same thing:

```
int x = new int();
```

and

```
int x = default(int);
```

both make an int initialized to zero.

For a class, they do not do the same thing:

```
Fruit f = new Fruit();
```

makes a new fruit reference and assigns the reference to variable f, whereas:

```
Fruit f = default(Fruit);
```

is the same as

```
Fruit f = null;
```

No constructor is called.

Comment: Loosely it describes Intrinsic data Types as a set of well defined common type system data types that resolve to the same type defined in mscorlib.dll.  E.G. System.String > String^ > string

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: Then in that case yes, the "intrinsic" data types all have a public parameterless ctor except for "string". But that's just a coincidence; all the "intrinsic" data types are structs except for "string" and "object", so clearly almost all of them must have a public parameterless ctor merely by virtue of being structs.

Answer (score 5):

> All intrinsic data types support what is known as a default constructor. It allows you to create a variable using the new keyword.

I'm not sure what the author means by "intrinsic data types". My best guess is that he actually means "value types" (i.e. types declared with C#'s `struct` keyword), because value types always have a default constructor, and reference types may not.

So if you have a field whose type is a `struct` type (e.g. Int32, CancellationToken), then that field will be initialized as if the type's default constructor was called.

In actual implementation, there's probably not an *actual* call to the type's default constructor -- the memory is just initialized to all zeroes, which is the same thing that would happen if you *did* call the default constructor. (That's why you can't provide your own parameterless constructor for a value type -- the parameterless constructor *always* initializes the memory to all zeroes. This greatly simplifies things like `new int[10000]` -- the compiler doesn't actually have to call `new Int32()` 10,000 times; it just zeroes out the memory.)

Your question about a `string` field in a `class` isn't really related to the author's discussion of "intrinsic data types", because both `string` and your enclosing `class` are reference types, not value types. So your class won't have a parameterless-constructor-that-you-can't-override; it will just have normal constructors. But the zeroing-out behavior is still there: when you call a constructor, the new memory block is zeroed out before the constructor code starts to run. Your `string` field is a reference type, and a zero reference is `null`.

Comment: More information on parameterless value-type constructors here: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/12/10/value-types-and-parameterless-constructors.aspx

Comment: What are intrinsic data types is here.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221332(v=vs.85).aspx 

Other are for example XAML https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/xaml-intrinsic-data-types

Comment: @MaciejKlemarczyk Your first link is for C++ and your second is for XAML and WPF. Neither has any relevance for general discussions of the C# language or the .NET runtime.

Comment: Here you can find more about C# string types and how it should behave https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types You need to take into account that behaviour you are describing can change in future versions of C# syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine it is using default(string) which returns null because string is a reference type.

Also, remember that constructors can't return null.

Comment: **Constructors** cannot return null because constructors never return a value at all; a constructor is a void-returning method.  I think you mean to say that the result *of the `new` operator* is never null.